# Web Audio API or <audio> for complex playlist?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm a Javascript dilettante. I need to make a webpage for mobile viewing to deploy a dynamically created but ultimately linear audio piece. Essentially I would need to load a playlist, in which some tracks are fixed but others are randomly chosen from a larger pool; there also need to be timed pauses between some of the tracks. It would need only minimal controls, probably just play/pause.

I'm looking into Web Audio API and the basic HTML5 `<audio>` tag. My two main concerns for choosing between them are **compatibility** and **simplicity of use**.

On the **compatibility** point, I see that [on the main page for the API itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibility) it lists no support for Android, but on [this more detailed rundown](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) almost all browsers are listed as green. What's the best source to trust?

Assuming Web Audio API is viable for mobile deployment, do I need to use it? Would it make my life easier or is it just overpowered for my purposes? I see it has a handy `onended` event handler which I see myself using for queuing, and precise timing functions. It also seems to be more explicit about loading the files asynchronously with a callback function on success - I'd want to have a loading screen so that would be useful.

I'm a bit less clear on the capabilities of `<audio>`. I guess it must be able to do everything I want given HTML5 players have been built before Web Audio API came along - but is it more fiddly?

Comment: The MDN documents are out-of-date; https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Web Audio works just fine on mobile.

Web Audio, in contrast to `<audio>`, breaks apart and give the developer precise control over the loading, decoding and playing of audio.  If you need precise timing - like, beat-synching - of audio, you should probably use web audio.  `<audio>` is pretty imprecise.

That said, a few caveats - as Web Audio by default uses in-memory buffers, it can use a lot more memory than `<audio>`, and it doesn't have native components to do streaming audio.  The onended event is NOT the right way to do real chaining of audio, because it's a main-thread-Javascript callback (that is to say, any event handling like this might be delayed by other JS, garbage collection, etc. - and it might be off by 50 or 100 milliseconds).  If you really care about timing, you have to plan ahead and use Web Audio scheduling.  ([This article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) I wrote describes this in more detail.)

Comment: Thanks for this. The fact that it's all in-memory is definitely an issue, as I'm looking at possibly 10 minute-long audio files. I knew `AudioBuffer`s are memory buffers but thought I could use `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`s. Now I see those are based on `<audio>` elements though. And thanks for pointing that out about `onended`. To be fair, I don't particularly need even millisecond accuracy for my purposes. PS. I had just read your article before posting that! It was helpful.